# How to affect all elements in class?

Tags: css

Hey this is probably a dumb question but i can't seem to find a straight answer.
How can i, for example, affect all the anchors in a class?

I've tried :

```
a.classname
```

and

```
.classname a
```

But don't seem to work.
Can Anyone give a straight answer for me and other future googlers?

Comment: What does "in a class" mean? For either meaning, you already have the answer.  Beware of specificity issues; use Firebug.

Comment: I'd suggest spending some time to learn the fundamentals of CSS, this is about as basic as it gets.

Comment: *all elements* would be `.classname *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.classname` is all `<a>` tags with a class of `"classname"`.

`.classname a` is all `<a>` tags that are a child of an element with class `"classname"`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HTxeQ/

NOTE:  If you have a more specific CSS rule elsewhere, it may overwrite that rule.

For example, `body .classname a` would overwrite `.classname a`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HTxeQ/1/

Comment: if that doesn't work, you could have some problems with it elsewhere. some times '.classname a' will fail if you also do something like '#parent .classname' somewhere else in the code. in which case you can either remove '#parent' from all of the existing rules, or simply add it to your new rules. '#list #of #parents .classname a' should work without flaw, *if* push comes to shove. however, I would never actually recommend writing your CSS like this, because if you *have* to do this to get it to work, then you've already seen why you shouldn't do this in the first place.

Comment: @andrewjackson: You're right, if there's a more specific rule elsewhere in the CSS, it may overwrite this rule.  http://jsfiddle.net/HTxeQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

This would change the color to white of all the Links within an element with the class "classname"

```
.classname a { color:white; }

<div class="classname">
  <a>Im now white</a>
  <a>Im now white</a>
  <a>Im now white</a>
</div>
```